# Rejected edit accidentally - Can we revoke the rejection we made?

Tags: support, editing, review

I was reviewing the edits suggested by @InnovaITveSolutions to this question [how-to-prevent-dependency-injection-from-killing-object-oriented-programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349131/how-to-prevent-dependency-injection-from-killing-object-oriented-programming) and accidentally voted to reject it. (Apologises)

Can we revoke our own vote?

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at it. Rejection seems appropriate in this case - the edits are extremely minor and do not significantly improve the post. One of the edits even added "emphasized text", which is the helper when you click on the italics button above the post box instead of actual italicized text.

I don't see a need to do anything with this post. Even though you may have clicked Reject by accident, you accidentally did the right thing.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding my second question, do I did well asking here? I wouldn't like end up using the Meta site as an issue tracker

Comment: @Laiv Questions like this is what Meta exists for.